# A footnote refers to the wrong document - what is a word to describe this kind of mistake?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, logic, reference

Well, the title question says it all I think:

A footnote refers to the wrong document - what is a word to describe this kind of mistake?

Words like "discrepancy", "incongruence", "fallacy", or simply "mistake" may be fine, but I am presuming this specific kind of error has its own terminology.

Comment: Misattribution?

Comment: Screw-up, perhaps?

Comment: I agree, but I have to write this down for s serious-type person.

Answer (score 2):

Mistake is fine, but [typographical error.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typographical%20error) might be better:

> a mistake (such as a misspelled word) in typed or printed text

This makes it clear that it's likely a mistake as a result of writing the information down, rather than with methodology, or logic, or something else.